# Pulling alt text from wordpress images

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm trying to pull the alt text from an image array to use elsewhere but i'm getting nowhere..

here's the code:

```
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 12, 'post_type' => 'clientes', 'orderby' => 'ASC');
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        $alt_text = get_post_meta($args , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); 

        ?>
        <li>
            <!--BEGIN .hentry -->
            <div class="post_box">
                <div class="post-thumb left gallery">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                        <div class="overlay"><img src="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>.jpg" /></div>
                    </a>

                </div>    
            <!--END .hentry-->  
            </div>
```

I'm pretty certain that my fault is with this line:

```
            $alt_text = get_post_meta($args , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

but I lack the knowledge to fix it...

thanks

b

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta): the first argument should be the post identifier *not* an array of args.

you need to call `get_post_meta` inside the `foreach` loop to pull each post's unique data:

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
$alt_text = get_post_meta($post->ID , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
endforeach;
```

Comment: hey and good morning. so i tried your solution but to no avail! See my post below for more info.. the lack of "return" in this reply box is killing me..

Comment: try to `var_dump` $alt_text, if you receive `false`, it means that there is no such meta_key for the post. you can double check it by var dumping the entire `$post` in the loop and searching for the meta key

Comment: It's pulling nothing! I'm just getting a sting of `string '' (length=0)` as the output. I've double checked that there is alt text there also.

Comment: Any ideas as to why its not finding anything in the alt field?

Comment: This is the output btw: `<li>
                <!--BEGIN .hentry -->
                <div class="post_box">
                    <div class="post-thumb left gallery">
                        <a href="">
       <img width="230" height="145" src="http://**url**/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/vgaccess-b.jpg" class="attachment-full colorbox-1106  wp-post-image" alt="vgaccess" />       <div class="overlay"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/.jpg" /></div>
      </a>

     </div>    
                <!--END .hentry-->  
                </div>`

Comment: I've dumped is the entire $post below and it appears that there is no alt meta key after all!!

Comment: go back to the foundation: open the DB and look for the table `wp_postmeta`. This table saves all the meta data as key=>value pairs. Look for you key there, and see if it exists

Comment: Hey, it appears that wordpress isn't saving the alt text in the post meta. I'm now just using <?php echo $post->post_name; ?> to give me a similar result. And sorry for posting below, editing the question somehow slipped my mind!